# Java regex contained within

Tags: java, regex

How can I write a regex to see if a certain string is contained within two characters.

For example, I want to see which part of the string is contained within a quotation mark.

```
Java"_virtual_"machine
```

If I run my regex through this, I want to get `_virtual_`

How can I achieve this using regexes?

Comment: Take a look at the javadoc of [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and show us what you tried.

Comment: @Raphaël I tried a bunch of messy stuff that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing the text contains only one such pair of characters and there are no escaping tricks or so, you can use this regex

```
.*"([^"]*)".*
```

[Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/eI4zY7/1)

Comment: What if there can be any number and you can escape the quotation marks? (Im sure you can solve that part with a lookbehind...)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do it with regex but with method which finds first and second occurrence of a character so it's more flexible to use in the

```
String s = "Java\"_virtual_\"machine";
String find = "\"";
int first = s.indexOf(find) + 1;
int second = s.indexOf(find, s.indexOf(find) + 1);
s.substring(first, second);
```

You can reuse this code on other characters and I bet it's faster than regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex. I'm not sure if this is the best regex you can use though. It will capture every string between quotes.

```
.*?"([^"]*)"
```

[**Demo here**](https://regex101.com/r/yC7sV0/2)

If you want to get the first string that matches the regex, use :

```
.*?"([^"]*)".*
```